# Отправка почты в Delphi с помощью Synapse

Tags: synapse, delphi

Есть ли у кого нибудь рабочий код отправки почты в `Delphi` с помощью Synapse? (с экзешником)
В интернете куча примеров но не один не отправляет почту

Comment: @Naruto, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,httpsend, mimemess, mimepart, smtpsend,synachar;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
Procedure SendMail (Host, Subject, pTo, From , TextBody,
                HTMLBody, login,password : string);
var Msg : TMimeMess; // сообщение
    StringList : TStringList; // содержимое письма
    MIMEPart : TMimePart; // части сообщения (на будущее)
begin
  Msg := TMimeMess.Create; // создаем новое сообщение
  IdealCharsets:=[CP1251];
  Msg.Header.CharsetCode:=CP1251;  // Установим кодировку  заголовков
//{$IFNDEF CIL} //error URW778 ??? :-O
//, GB2312, EUC_KR, ISO_2022_JP, EUC_TW  {$ENDIF}  ];

  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // Добавляем заголовки
    Msg.Header.Subject := Subject;// тема сообщения
    Msg.Header.From := From; // имя и адрес отправителя
    Msg.Header.ToList.Add(pTo); // имя и адрес получателя
    // создаем корневой элемент
    MIMEPart := Msg.AddPartMultipart('alternative', nil);
    if length(TextBody)=0 then
    // если формат HTML
      begin
        StringList.Text := HTMLBody;
        Msg.AddPartHTML(StringList, MIMEPart);
      end
    else
    // если текстовый формат
      begin
        StringList.Text := TextBody;
        Msg.AddPartText(StringList, MIMEPart);
      end;
    // Кодируем и отправляем
    Msg.EncodeMessage;
    // Отправляем.
    if smtpsend.SendToRaw(From,pTo,Host,Msg.Lines,login,password) then
        ShowMessage('Письмо отправлено')
    else
        ShowMessage('Письмо не отправлено');
 finally
   Msg.Free;
   StringList.Free;
 end;
end;
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

 SendMail('smpt.yandex.com',
        'tema testovogo pisma',
        'test@mail.ru',
        'test@yandex.ru',
        'Soderzhimoe pisma v textovom formate',
        '',
        'test', '**********')

end;

end.
```

Comment: @Naruto, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.